# Event listener and event dispatching process

Tags: android, android-widget

For onTouch listener, the function is

public boolean onTouch( View v, MotionEvent event )

based on the tutorial I'm following, it stated that return true - we have already processed the event ; return false - View itself will process the event

I can't really understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is used when there are Views on top of other Views. Imagine there are a stack of Views as follows:

```
View A
View B
```

So the user would see View A and then View B would be under it. If View A has an onTouch listener, it will get invoked whenever a touch occurs on that View. If false is returned, then the touch event will be passed to View B and View B's onTouch listener (if it has one), can then go and handle the touch event.

Does that make sense?

Comment: understood..~ can i know how to stack the Views?

Comment: The way the Views are organized (stacked) is based on your layout